# How do I type a nilpotent matrix?

Tags: matrices

So I am now doing my work in mathematics and I need to type a nilpotent matrix just like that in Sheldon Axler's Linear algebra done right, page 249.
I tried multiple times but it doesn't look like the same, may anyone help? Here is the sketch: [image]

Comment: Welcome. Can you please add a sketch? Or maybe a scan of the particular part?

Comment: Can you also add one of your multiple attempts?

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
    \ 0&&*\ \\
    &\ddots\\
    \ 0&&0\ \end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

It will give you this:

[image]

Comment: You might want to add some spaces between the corner symbols and the parentheses.  Not absolutely necessary, but it looks nicer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a nice suggestion. I've added it to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try this, to make nearly the same as the example image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\;\begin{matrix}
    0&&*\\
    &\ddots\\
    0&&0\end{matrix}\;\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

`\;` is an abbreviated form of 'thick spacing' command. Others are `\,` for thin, `\:` for medium. `\left` and `\right` allows to scale up parentheses and brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the section title, this looks very much like the given picture. Not something I'd typeset myself, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[textwidth=10cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{8}
\setcounter{subsection}{18}

\subsection{Matrix of a nilpotent operator}

Suppose $N$ is a nilpotent operator on~$V$. Then there is a basis
of~$V$ with respect to which the matrix of~$N$ has the form
\[
\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & & * \\ & \ddots & \\ 0 & & 0 \end{array}\right);
\]
here all entries on and below the diagonal are $0$'s.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Except the section number and title might be in sans serif but why would anyone want to mix them up?